# What is a DocuSign template's documentID?

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I'm using a DocuSign template that has multiple documents. I want to use composite templates to substitute a new document at runtime.

**How do I determine the document ID that the template is using?**

Answer (score 0):

The template's first document usually has ID 1.

To see a specific document ID:

1. Open the template for editing
2. Click View for the document of interest
3. On the document's modal display: open the browser's menu and choose "Open image in new tab"
4. Inspect the new tab's URL. The number after /documents/ is the document ID. Eg URL .../documents/456/pages/... has document ID 456